# Powershell script to deploy files with necessary backup

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-2.0

Team,
I'm writing a powershell script  to automate one of the manual task we are doing daily. I need expert suggestion and help here as I'm new to powershell scripting.

Requirement:

There is a source, destination and a backup folder.

Source may have diff files and files within multiple folders of source.

**eg**: source\Login.aspx or source\App_Code\BLogic.vb or source\bin\servr.dll etc.

While copying to **destination**, my **source** file has to be checked for existence at destination, if exists then we need to copy the current existing file in **destination** to **backup** folder, then copy **source** to **destination**.

Below are the scripts that i have tried till now.

Script1:

I'm able to list files which are same but not able to copy those array elements to backup location:

```
#Declare Source and Destination
$source = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path \\server1\\e$\ps\src\
$dest = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path \\server2\\e$\ps\dest\
#lists only objects which are equal and assign to variable
$files=compare-Object -DifferenceObject $source -ReferenceObject $dest -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$array = @($files)
$len=$array.length
for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) 
{
 $array[$i]
}
```

Script2:

As script1 i was facing problem i tried a silly logic with this script, but i feel this is also having too much manual work :( please help me.

```
Function cpytest ($s, $d)
{
Copy-Item -Path $s -Destination $d;
}
$n = Read-Host "Enter no of files to be uploaded"
$b = Read-Host "Enter Backup Location for file backups"
for ($i=0;$i -lt $n;$i++)
  {
   $s = Read-Host "Enter Source with complete file name"
   $d = Read-Host "Enter Destination with file name too"
   $r = Test-Path $d
   If ($r -eq "True")
   { 
    cpytest $d $b
    cpytest $s $d
    }
   Else
   {
   cpytest $s $d
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why not just copy the whole directory to the backup location and then overwrite it with the new version?

Comment: We need to keep 1 month backup with all the file versions, its development team requirement.

Comment: Also, some application logic includes upload docs in application folder as well which are more than a GB or GB+, so keeping another copy is space consuming.

Comment: Your development team should have everything in version control and records of what gets deployed when - and be able to recreate any state at any time from those sources. Having backups is good for your disaster recovery plans, but it sounds like you're making backups of things that should already exist elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Function BackupAndMoveFile($filePath, $backupPath, $deployPath) {

    $fileName = Split-Path $filePath -Leaf

    $deployFile = Join-Path $deployPath $fileName

    if ((Test-Path $deployFile)) {
        $backupFile = Join-Path $backupPath $fileName
        Move-Item $deployFile $backupFile -Force
        if (!(Test-Path $backupFile)) {
            Write-Warning "Can't backup $fileName to $backupFile"
            return $false
        }
    }

    Copy-Item $filePath $deployPath -Force
    if (!(Test-Path $deployPath)) {
        Write-Warning "Can't deploy $fileName to $deployPath"
        return $false
    }

    return $true
}


BackupAndMoveFile 'C:\temp\backup-test.txt' `
                  'C:\temp\backup' `
                  'C:\temp\deploy'
```

It will overwrite anything in the backup directory so you might want to modify to add a timestamp.

Comment: thanks a lot for the script. This is very much working for a single file. Can I get the logic or sample code to do multiple file copies with one time function call? I'm trying to put this in for loop but still if my application have 100 files to be moved then its difficult to call function so many times..